# What's the recommended way to import libraries inside webpack.config.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I always used `require` call inside `webpack.config.js` to import libraries for my build workflow. However, recently I worked on a project where `import` is used.

Generally, it works fine but seems like some supporting tools that import `webpack.config.js` cannot import it when `import` is used inside of it with error:

> Cannot use `import` statement outside a module.

As a tryout, I changed the config to run through babel and it worked, though for me looks like I am fine to use just good old `require` and official documentation still uses it.

Should I rollback `import` to avoid the caveats or I can use them without problem if I pass it through babel and renaming to `webpack.config.babel.js`?

Comment: Using babel on server side is pointless unless you must(for some reason) use really deprecated version of node.js and modern syntax. You have absolutely no control over client platform => thats why babel. On the server side, you can easily upgrade and/or lock environment for several years. Import support is relatively new to node.js env. My advice to avoid headaches - use CommonJS.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I got to a solution - transpile webpack config before passing it to a library I used which failed to load it (eslint-import-resolver-webpack).

So, I don't load `webpack.config.js` directly, but via babel transpiler:

```
const webpackConfigTranspiled = babel.transformFileSync(
  path.resolve(__dirname, './webpack.config.js'),
).code;
```

Then pass the transpiled content to the library/tool:

```
settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      webpack: webpackConfigTranspiled,
    },
    'css-modules': {
      basePath: 'src',
    },
  }
```